# How to connect values in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I'm sorry if the title of my question doesn't make too much sens. I will try to explain the best I can.

**MySQL table:**

[image]

**Context:**

In my python code, the user can input a company name. The company name is verified in `Company` column. If it finds it in the column, it runs the the next code, or else it prints back an error.

**What I need:**

When the user input the company name, i want to assign its corresponding `employe_1` name to a variable. So, if user input `Company` "XYZ", it should automaticaly assign "Alex" to a variable.

**Existing code**

This is my code so far:

```
 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="nn", passwd="passpass")

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    company_name = input()
    mycursor.execute("""SELECT employe_1 FROM listedatabase.entreprises_inspecteurs WHERE employe_1 = %s"""(company_name,))
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    if data:
        code goes there
    else: 
        print('data not found in database')
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Start by fixing your broken schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet! Companies and Employees belong in separate tables.

Comment: It's not a broken schema. You have absolutely no idea of the reality of our company. Instead of downvoting and judging, you should ask me about it first. Thanks for your input. @Strawberry

Comment: I don't anything about your company. I do know what normalised data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the `employee_1` column name in the query and if the data is available, access it as show below.

```
company_name = input()
    mycursor.execute("""SELECT n_fabricant, employee_1 FROM listedatabase.entreprises_inspecteurs WHERE n_fabricant = %s"""(company_name,))
    data = mycursor.fetchall() # Instead of fetchall, use fetchone if the query is expected to return only one row
    if data:
        row = data[0]
        variable = row[1]
        # remaining code
```